# iOS Swift 3/XCode 8 Right Constraint Not Being Applied

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, swift3, constraints

I'm trying to build a form programmatically using Swift 3 and for some reason the right constraints is not being applied when running the app.

What I have is a `UIScollView` which contains a `UITextField` as you can see from the preview below the ScrollView is red and the TextField is white.

```
// View Controller Properties
var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var firstName: UITextField!

// Inside viewDidLoad()
self.scrollView = UIScrollView()
self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)

let top     = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrollView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let left    = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrollView, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let right   = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrollView, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let bottom   = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrollView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

self.view.addConstraints([top, left, right, bottom])



self.firstName = UITextField()
self.firstName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.firstName.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
self.firstName.placeholder = "First Name"

self.scrollView.addSubview(self.firstName)

let top     = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.firstName, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.scrollView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
let left    = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.firstName, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.scrollView, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
let right   = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.firstName, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.scrollView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let height   = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.firstName, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40)

self.scrollView.addConstraints([top, right, left, height])
```

I tried using `.trailing` and `.trailingMargin` instead but nothing is working. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
```

Note: For iOS 9 +